# how to add change language dropdown to Django(1.10) admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, multilingual, django-multilingual

I'm planning to add change language dropdown in my admin page.
according to [this code](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/751/) and [How to extend admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978260/how-do-i-correctly-extend-the-django-admin-base-html-template). 
I copy `base_site.html` and copy it to `myapp/templates/admin`, the i create a html file named `change_language.html` and write this code in it:

```
{% load i18n %}
/ {% trans 'Change language' %}
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post" style="display: inline;">
  <div style="display: inline;">
    <select name="language" onchange="javascript:form.submit()">
      {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
        <option value="{{ lang.0 }}"{% ifequal LANGUAGE_CODE lang.0 %} selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>{{ lang.1 }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

I add `{% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}` at the top of this file, noting happens.
I add `{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}` , again noting happens.
All hints and answers says that we should change something name `<div id="user-tools">` at line 25 of `base.html`, But in Django 1.10 it goes to line 31 with a different staff. im kinnda lost because i read many different staff every where  and non of them works for me. Dose any know where im doing wrong ?

here is my middlewares :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

And template settings :

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Comment: Can you post your middleware and template engines?

Comment: Sure. i Update my question dear @rfkortekaas

Answer (score 2):

In your templates/admin folder, make sure the file is named *base_site.html* (otherwise the default base_site will not be overwritten).

Make sure to copy the latest version of the file from the [django-repo](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html).

Most important: verify you extend the admins base.html (your base_site.html should start with `{% extends "admin/base.html" %}`)

You may now add your form (for example to the footer):

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
<div id="footer">
    <form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="language">
            {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                <option value="{{ lang.0 }}"
                    {% ifequal lang.0 request.LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                        selected="yes"
                    {% endifequal %}
                >{{ lang.1 }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Change language' %}" />
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Refer to the [base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) to find a block that seems suitable for your form.

You will also need to add the [i18n urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) to your url-settings

`url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),`

And if you really want to submit your form using javascript you will also need to get and submit the csrf token for the form. The [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax) cover this topic quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kim's answer, you should add *i18n* context processor in your django settings `django.template.context_processors.i18n` to be able to access **LANGUAGES** variable in the template.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just looking at the admin site and language list it empty. After adding this I got the list

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are mixing both answers that you've found on the internet. One of them copies and changes a couple of files from the admin template, effectively overriding them in your program's references. The second one extends admin's templates. You should completely implement just one of them.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?
if i want to copy the base.html file, where should i copy it ?
and how it works ?

Comment: here is the code from base.html https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html

Comment: your first link suggests copying this and changing line 25 (or 28 in this example) tp include your new html file (change_language.html)

Comment: your second answer suggests creating another html file (for example base_site.html so it doesn't conflict with base.html) and extending a block in the original base.html. In this case you should replace the userlinks block with the new code.

Comment: Do you know how can i access the LANGUAGES ?
in my `change_languages.html` the `select` comes with no option ?
can you help me ? @navit

Comment: not helping... my languages are sets. and works correctly with urls.. it just not load in the select options.

Comment: It is just not different from any other template. Anyhow you are loading your language in a normal template, you can do this here.